# Will Angular re-render whole object?

Tags: angular

There is a data I render in template using async.

```
  private registry = new BehaviorSubject<RegistryGroup[]>([]);
```

Template is:

```
*ngFor="let reg of registry | async"
```

Also there is a function that modifies data and pushed beck to `registry`:

```
modify(registryId: number) {
    const updated = this._registry.getValue().map((registry) => {
      if (registry.Id == registryId) {
        registry.opened = true;
      }
      return registry;
    });

    this.registry.next(updated);
  }
```

Will Angular render whole `registry` or only changed element `registry.opened = true;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to optimize re-rendering you should use **trackBy** function, which should return unique (usually id) value for each value in array